# entering date in a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have a button, which when clicked will give the current date and time in a text box.then I used another program to move that to cell.but this are not considered as the date until I double-clicked it.during filtering,this entered date are excluded from other dates

i have done formatting for date(ddmmyy HHmm)

```
Private Sub CommandButton5_Click()



If Not TextBox6.Value = "" Then

ans = msgbox(" Date already exits.Do you want to continue", vbYesNo + vbQuestion)



If ans = vbYes Then

TextBox6.Value = Format(Now(), ddmmyyHHmm)

End If

End If


If TextBox6.Value = "" Then


TextBox6.Value = Format(Now(), ddmmyyHHmm)

End If



End Sub
```

and for copying  value to cell ,i used
    cells(i,"A").value = textbox6.value

Comment: `Format` returns a `Variant/String`. You want to enter an actual date/time in the cell.

Comment: May i know how i can do it here

Comment: Just a clarification: you should have quotes around the format type, right: `Format(Now(), "ddmmyyHHmm")`? Won't fix your issue but maybe a typo in your question?

Answer (score 0):

`Format` returns a `Variant/String`. You want to enter an actual date/time into the cell, not a formatted one that Excel no longer recognizes as a date.

One option is to use `DateSerial` and `TimeSerial` to build up a true date/time from that string. There's probably a simpler way to achieve this though, but anyway, here's an example:

```
Dim x As String
x = TextBox6.Value

Dim yy As Integer, dd As Integer, mm As Integer, hh As Integer, min As Integer
yy = CInt(Mid(x, 5, 2)) ' year
mm = CInt(Mid(x, 3, 2)) ' month
dd = CInt(Mid(x, 1, 2)) ' day
hh = CInt(Mid(x, 7, 2)) ' hour
min = CInt(Mid(x, 9, 2)) ' minute

Cells(i, "A").Value = DateSerial(yy, mm, dd) + TimeSerial(hh, min, 0)
```

If you want to format the cell with that date/time formatting:

```
Cells(i, "A").NumberFormat = "ddmmyyHHmm"
```